# how to find urls under double quote

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url, preg-match

let's say we load the source code of this question and we want to find the url alongside "**childUrl**"

or goto this site source code and search "**childUrl**".

```
<?php
$sites_html = file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272862/how-to-find-urls-under-double-quote");
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($sites_html);
foreach() {
# now i want here to echo the link alongside "childUrl"
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use regex:
try this code

```
$matches = [[],[]];
preg_match_all('/\"wanted_url\": \"([^\"]*?)\"/', $sites_html, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match;
}
```

this will print all urls with wanted_url tag

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in C:\wamp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: you said that this document contains
"key": "value"

Comment: @Emmanuel
try the code now
be sure that $sites_html contains the urls
as you said they are like: "key": "value"
if they are like that
you can use this code

Comment: @hassan thanks in advance, but  it is not working, if u can run the full code and check it.

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel
this is a working code from my terminal

$urls =  '"url1": "http://notneeded.com", "url2": "http://notneeded.net", "wanted_url": "http://wantedurl1.com", "wanted_url": "https://wantedurl3.com"';
 $matches = [[], []];

preg_match_all('/\"wanted_url\": \"([^\"]*?)\"/', $urls, $matches);


 foreach($matches[1] as $match) {echo $match . ', '; }
http://wantedurl1.com, https://wantedurl3.com, ⏎
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    function extract($url){
    $sites_html = file_get_contents("$url");
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $$html->loadHTML($sites_html);

      foreach ($html->loadHTML($sites_html) as $row)
      {
       if($row=="wanted_url") 
       {
         echo $row;
       }
     }
 }
?>
```

Comment: i got this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string"

Comment: <?php
    function extract($url){
    $sites_html = file_get_contents("$url");
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $$html->loadHTML($sites_html);

      foreach ($html->loadHTML($sites_html) as $row)
      {
       if((string)$row=="wanted_url") 
       {
         echo $row;
       }
     }
 }
?>